# Qml Image inside Flickable zoom shifts (and clips)

Tags: qt, qml, zooming

I am trying to add zoom controls to my image. I tried to start as simple as possible, but anything I try ends up clipping the image.

The image is loaded in a part of the screen, and I want to place it in a `Flickable`, to be able to zoom and pan. I will add pinch and mouse wheel later, for now I have buttons to set various scale values.

The problem: when zoomed, the image is shifted and clipped. The shift is bothersome, because the zoomed image being bigger than the container, why show the empty space ? But the clipping is much worse, and I don't understand it. Seems the shift is as big as the clip (maybe?).

I tried to change the `transformOrigin`, not good. I tried to use `transform` instead of `scale`, but I saw nothing happen.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 1015; height: 550; visible: true
    Item {      // A bunch of buttons to easily test several zoom values and layout is similar
        id: leftSideContainer; width: 100; height: parent.height
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent; Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter;
            Layout.preferredHeight: 40; Layout.fillWidth: true;
            Button { text: "50 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 0.5; }
            Button { text: "80 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 0.8; }
            Button { text: "100 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 1; }
            Button { text: "110 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 1.1; }
            Button { text: "120 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 1.2; }
            Button { text: "150 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 1.5; }
            Button { text: "200 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 2; }
            Button { text: "400 %"; onClicked: imageContainer.imageScale = 4; }
            Button { text: "landscape"; onClicked: { paintedCanvasImage.source = ""; paintedCanvasImage.source = "/examples/landscape.jpg"; } }
            Button { text: "portrait"; onClicked: { paintedCanvasImage.source = ""; paintedCanvasImage.source = "/examples/portrait.jpg"; } }
            Button { text: "square"; onClicked: { paintedCanvasImage.source = ""; paintedCanvasImage.source = "/examples/square.jpg"; } }
        }
    }
    Item {  // Using separate variable and item a bit like my code
        id: imageContainer; property var imageScale: 1;
        anchors { left: leftSideContainer.right; right: parent.right;
                  top: parent.top; bottom: parent.bottom; }
        Rectangle {  // Easy to show background compared to actual image, no other use
            anchors.fill: parent; color: "lightgreen"; }

        onImageScaleChanged: paintedCanvasImage.scale = imageScale;

        Flickable { // I want to pan
            id: flickImage
            anchors.fill: parent

            contentWidth: paintedCanvasImage.paintedWidth * paintedCanvasImage.scale
            contentHeight: paintedCanvasImage.paintedHeight * paintedCanvasImage.scale
            //contentX: ??? I have no idea
            clip: true   // required
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { active: true; policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded; }
            ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { active: true; policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded; }

            Image {
                id: paintedCanvasImage
                width: imageContainer.width; height: imageContainer.height
                source: "/examples/landscape.jpg"  // Trying square, landscape or portrait
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit   // required
                transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft       // With this, weirdly the vertical fits correctly, horizontal only shifted/clipped
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample run: I will show 100, and 200% top-left and bottom-right, to show clipping and empty area. Note that with `transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft` the image fits vertically (if the container is more landscape-y than the image, or horizontally otherwise) - but is shifted by some amount that I don't know, to the right:

[image: 100 %]
[image: 200 % top-left with transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft]
[image: 200 % bottom-right with transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft]

I cannot figure out what the `transformOrigin` should be, or how to use `transform` instead of `scale`, or what the flickable's origin must be. 
Changing `contentX` I thought would fix it, but it doesn't - something about the transform must be needed.

Platform: windows as well as embedded linux; 
Qt version: 5.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code that are causing the problem.
First, the clipping issue is due to the absence of `transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft`, which causes the origin to be the center by default and makes your image scale in negative x and y.
The shifting issue is caused by the `paintedWidth` value, which, according to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedWidth-prop), can be less than the image item.
Additionally, using `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit` will always result in empty spaces around your image if its ratio doesn't fit your `container`.

For the solution, I made a few more changes so that you can easily use the wheel or pinch handler.

In the following code, I added a `fitSize` property which stores the initial size of the image, and it also calculates the aspect ratio using the `sourceSize` of the image. I also removed the scaling part of the image to be able to use `flickable.resizeContent`.

By multiplying `fitSize` with `iscale`, you can get new sizes.

It may not be best practice, but it works well, and I think you could also use a `PinchHandler` instead of `WheelHandler`.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Page {
    id: root

    implicitWidth: 550
    implicitHeight: 300

    contentItem: Control {
        id: container

        property real iscale: 1
        property size fitSize: {
            const ss = image.sourceSize;
            const ratio = ss.width / ss.height;
            return ratio < width/height ? Qt.size(height * ratio, height) : Qt.size(width, width / ratio);
        }

        contentItem: Flickable {
            id: flickable

            clip: true

            leftMargin: Math.max(0, width - contentWidth) / 2 // Centering the content
            topMargin: Math.max(0, height - contentHeight) / 2

            contentWidth: container.fitSize.width
            contentHeight: container.fitSize.height

            rebound: Transition {}
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {}

            Image {
                id: image

                width: flickable.contentWidth
                height: flickable.contentHeight
                source: "path/to/image.jpg"
                onSourceChanged: container.iscale = 1

                MouseArea {
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onWheel: function(e) {
                        const { width, height } = container.fitSize;
                        const mousePos = Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY);

                        container.iscale += e.angleDelta.y / 1200;
                        flickable.resizeContent(width * container.iscale, height * container.iscale, mousePos);
                        flickable.returnToBounds();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        background: Rectangle { color: "#121314" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try `transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft` - you saw it commented in my code, it still clips my image. `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit` is required. I am not zooming a container, but an image. The image starts as best fit, and then the user will zoom. And therefore, `paintedWidth` and `paintedHeight` are also correct. What I am missing is the `contentX` and `contentY`, I don't know how to get them to prevent clipping.

Comment: I tried to run your code but missing things that I don't know

Comment: @Thalia I have updated the source code and replaced `WheelHandler` with `MouseArea`, which doesn't seem to be available in version **2.12**. Additionally, I do not have direct access to **Qt 5.12**, so you may want to change `const { width, height } = container.fitSize;` and assign the width and height directly.

Comment: It works exactly as you have it, as updated, thanks - but strangely I can't get anything to show if I remove the "Page" and "contentItem" to use just "Item"

Comment: @Thalia To further explain your previous comment, when you set `width: imageContainer.width` in the Image component, the Image will attempt to stretch or fit itself within the given size. As a result, the paintedWidth may differ from the Image's width. Additionally, scaling does not change the Image's width, which means that Flickable cannot determine if its content has been resized or not. This forces you to manually set the contentWidth, which can cause the Image to be clipped on the bottom right side.

Comment: Additionally, the contentX value would change when flicking, and while you can modify it, doing so would conflict with the dragging functionality of the Flickable.

However, for the top left side, clipping only occurs if you remove `transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft`, which causes the image to grow from the center and be painted at a negative contentX. This will not be visible in the Flickable.
Even if you address all of these issues, attempting to add a mouse wheel event would be too difficult.

Comment: @Thalia You should set the `width` and `height` for the `container`. Using `contentItem: Control` would allow the parent to manage its `width` and `height`.