# How to properly stretch an image in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to apply 2 functions to the fitToWidth and fitToHeight images so that vertical scrolling should work with fitToWidth. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This code displays normally when opening an image. But even if you do rotation, the image does not adjust to the height of the parent but goes beyond the boundaries.
Maybe I need to swap the height and width of the image when rotation?
Maybe someone had such an experience?

```
Rectangle
{
    id: root

    required property url source
    property alias pageRotation:    image.rotation
    property alias scaleImage :     image.scale

    function goToPage(page)
    {
        pdfPageView.goToPage(page)
    }

    function scaleToPage(width, height)
    {
        image.scale = Math.min(
            root.width / (image.rot90 ? image.height : image.width),
            root.height / (image.rot90 ? image.width : image.height) )
        image.scale = 1
    }

    function scaleToWidth(width, height)
    {
      image.scale = root.width / (image.rot90 ? image.height : image.width)
        image.scale = 1
    }

    property size parentSize: Qt.size(root.width, root.height)
    onParentSizeChanged:
    {
//            image.scale(parentSize.width,parentSize.height)
    }

    Flickable
    {
        id: flickable

        width: root.width
        height: root.height

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            console.log("flickable: ", flickable.width, flickable.height)
        }

        contentWidth: pageHolder.width
        contentHeight: pageHolder.height

        ScrollBar.horizontal:
        ScrollBar {}

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar
        {
            width: 10

            contentItem: Rectangle
            {
                color: "#b6b6b6"
                radius: 10
            }
        }

        Rectangle
        {
            id: pageHolder

            width: root.width > image.width ? root.width : image.width
//            width: root.width
            height: root.height > image.height ? root.height : image.height
//            height: root.height

            color: "yellow"

            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                console.log("pageHolder: ", pageHolder.width, pageHolder.height)
            }


            Image
            {
                id: image

                property real rotationModulus: Math.abs(root.pageRotation % 180)
                property bool rot90: rotationModulus > 45 && rotationModulus < 135
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                height: root.height
                width: root.width

                 fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: root.source

                antialiasing: true
//                rotation: root.pageRotation

                Component.onCompleted:
                {
                    console.log("image: ", image.width, image.height)
                }

                onRotationChanged:
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel. If you need kind of stretch you probably have to use one of Layouts. A child item gets a transformation from its parent, you don't have to do it yourself in this case.

Comment: What is the `pdfPageView` here? See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77710612/11603485) would help you.

Comment: Forgot to correct this Image, as image.goToPage